# html5 getUserMedia Api stop webcam button not working

Tags: javascript, html, api, getusermedia

I am executing this code on localhost XAMPP Server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<video onclick="changeFilter(this);"width=200 height=200 id="video" controls autoplay></video> 
<p>
<button onclick="startWebcam();">Start WebCam</button>
<button onclick="stopWebcam();">Stop WebCam</button> 
</p>
 <script>
 navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.msGetUserMedia);

 var webcamStream;

 function startWebcam() {
 if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
 console.log("toto");
 navigator.getUserMedia (

    // constraints
    {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },

    // successCallback
     function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      webcamStream = localMediaStream;
    },

    // errorCallback
       function(err) {
       console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
       }
     );
    } else {
    console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
      }  
     }

  function stopWebcam() {
  localMediaStream.stop();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code starts my webcam, but when I press the `Stop WebCam` button the console gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined function stopWebcam() { webcamStream.stop(); }
```

I am a JavaScript newbie and I can not see the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

`localMediaStream` is not available to you in stopWebcam(). Check out this post for more on [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Try...

```
  function stopWebcam() {
      webcamStream.stop();
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much Madness!!! lol i just realized i needed to change it to that and then it worked!! good luck to you  and thank you for your help!!!